# Can an integer always be parsed as a long?

Tags: java, types

I have a list of strings in Java which are being written to a text file. These strings are each tagged with a type -- in this case, I'll I'm interested are strings containing `long`s and `int`s. I'd like to convert these strings back to a numeric type before writing them, but I'd like to minimize code duplication. I plan on parsing every string tagged as an integer or long integer using `Long.parseLong()`.

My question is this: are there any situations in which a valid integer will not parse as a long? I can't think of any (with the exception of maybe "1000L" or some such), but my experience in these matters has taught me that there are often nuances that I miss.

Comment: Technically the `1000L` is an example of when a valid `long` wouldn't parse as an `int`, not the other way around.

Comment: Ah, quite right. Not certain that there's an integer suffix, so I'll leave it as is and just acknowledge that it's wrong (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, integers can always be cast into long, but long cant always be cast into int.

An int is really a 4-byte whole number and a long is 8 bytes.  So a long gives you 4 more bytes from an int.

Answer (score 3):

`Long.parseLong("1000L")` results in a NumberFormatException -- it accepts string-encoded numeric values, not necessarily Java number literals (although there is a large overlap).

Because of this `Long.parseLong` encompasses `Integer.parseInt` entirely just as the values of `int` are a proper subset of the values of `long`.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine, since ints are a subset of longs.

Answer (score 0):

checking the description of the [both](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) [methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

the answer is no (except when l or L appears after the string)

Answer (score 0):

Every possible `int` value can be stored in a `long` or `double` (or BigInteger)